# Use an in app purchase product in different apps on Windows Store

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase, store

I have a series of similars apps which have in app purchases.
Can I create just 1 product and use it from every app. Or I have to create 1 product in all the apps....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In app purchases are specific to the app. Separate apps will need to each have their own products.

If you want to share state you would need to implement this yourself on a server that all of the apps could query.